# access_denied error while login to multi-tenant app with external user

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-graph-api

I Have implemented Multi tenant app.I have able login from other directory and same directory user but when i'm login with the external user or guest user then i'm getting access_denied error.

***Eg***:My directory domainname like **sample.onmicrosoft.com**.The user with **test@sample.onmicrosoft.com** able to login to my app but when the user like **test@sample-softwaresolutions.com** not able to login my app.

Error like below

```
#error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS65005%3a+Using application is currently not supported for your Organizationname.com.com because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of Organizationname.com. before the application AppName can be provisioned.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+1cc5197f-2580-4b09-8f22-e2ad20520900%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+13c719cf-ee2a-49d0-bb11-e9b84fb15843%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-09-24+12%3a20%3a03Z&state=b2662aef-dd29-4a80-b6fd-09e47d991934
```

or see the below image

[image]

**Any Answer Appreciated**

**Thanks in Advance......!**

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, you will have to verify your domain [DNS verification] as per the details given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-self-service-signup)

There are two modes to convert to managed app

> **Internal Takeover**
>   Let's say an IT administrator from Bellows College discovers that users from the school have signed up for self-service offerings. As the registered owner of the DNS name BellowsCollege.com, the IT administrator can validate ownership of the DNS name in Azure and then take over the unmanaged directory. The directory then becomes a managed directory, and the IT administrator is assigned the global administrator role for the BellowsCollege.com directory.
>
> **External Takeover** For example, let's say you are an IT administrator
>   and you already have a managed directory for Contoso.com, a domain
>   name that is registered to your organization. You discover that users
>   from your organization have performed self-service sign up for an
>   offering by using email domain name user@contoso.co.uk, which is
>   another domain name that your organization owns. Those users currently
>   have accounts in an unmanaged directory for contoso.co.uk.

There are more details on the given link.

Comment: Hi,Can you check the Example i have changed recently and replay me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is expected error because when the multi-tenant app is using `common` in the authorization endpoint. And Azure AD determine the Azure Active Directory by the account users input. So the Azure AD will take the default Azure Active Directory instead of the tenant the account was added to as a external users. This is reasonable since we may add the same users to many other directories.

So if we want the login with the external users for the multi-tenant app, we should use the specific tenant in the authorization endpoint instead of using `common`.

Comment: Hi,Can you check the Example i have changed recently and replay me.Thanks

Comment: @BalarajuPolaki As I mentioned instead of using `common` endpoint(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44320&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&nonce=123`), we should use the specific tenant like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/sample-softwaresolutions.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=eca61fd9-f491-4f03-a622-90837bbc1711&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44320&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net&nonce=123`

Comment: Hi Fei Xue,Thanks for replay,Actually my application is a multi tenant so if i put "sample-softwaresolutions.c‌​om" instead of "common" than it will accept only single tenant.

Comment: You are right. This is just a basic knowledge for this issue. When implement the solution in the scenario, you need to think about how to provide the UI. For example, the app may provide another entry page that require users enter the tenant they want to login-in as a external user instead of the default directory they belonged to.